# Is the context params removed in Gesture handler at latest version of react-native-gesture-handler?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm working on `react-native-reanimated` and `react-native-gesture-handler`.

First I learn the guides from reanimated, then is the gesture handler. But the demo code from them give me the type warnings about gesture handler, and there is no context params type on the gesture handler. I know that the ref object from `useRef` can be used instead of context params, but I would like to use the context if it be there.

The following is my code:

[image: code]

Answer (score 0):

here is example on how to use it:

```
const translateX = useSharedValue(0)
const translateY = useSharedValue(0)

const context = useSharedValue({ x: 0, y: 0 })

const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
  .onStart(() => {
    context.value = { x: translateX.value, y: translateY.value }
  })
  .onUpdate((event) => {
    translateX.value = event.translationX + context.value.x
    translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y
  })

const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
  return {
    transform: [{ translateX: translateX.value }, { translateY: translateY.value }],
  }
})
```